# How to fix this laminate flooring edge?

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor

I'm not all that DIY savvy and so had some guys come fit a laminate floor for me. It covers two floors, one of wood and one of concrete, and due to the different levels there's a reasonable amount of plywood under the floor to even it all out

This means, however, that the wooden floor which was previously level with the tiled floor next door is now about 1cm higher due to the laminate. The people who installed the floor added a small laminate ramp, which kind of worked OK but wasn't ideal, but it's since come loose

Does anyone have any better suggestions for what could finish off this flooring, or failing that any suggestions on how to fix the ramp in place?

Also, as a side quest, any ideas of what can be done about the gap on the left next to the doorframe?

[image]

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1):

That last piece should have been cut to match, well fill, the gap on the left.

If there is a waste piece available then you can cut a bit to just drop in at this point, unless you have a spare full board to cut properly.

As for the end trim - it needs securing properly either gluing or screwing as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Drill 2  pilot and countersink holes in the transition piece so that when screwed down they will hit the plywood subfloor.

The gap along the door jamb can be filled with colored caulking to hide it. Extending the wall molding will decrease it's size. Replacing the last section of flooring and cutting the end to fit better is the best solution.